# Dissimilarity matrices and autoencoders

Tags: r, neural-networks, clustering, feature-selection, autoencoders

As a thought experiment:

If I use an feed-forward autoencoder with sigmoidal activation to reduce a multi-dimensional dataframe of continous inputs to a two-dimensionsal representation...

Does a dissimilarity matrix from the two-dimensional feature vector with euclidean distance effectively represent similarity between observations?

i.e. is euclidean distance in the 2D feature-vector space between observations relevant when comparing observation similarity?

Thank you, let me know if I can clarify at all.